# gem 'backstretch-rails' and rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm kinda loss here, i installed backstretch-rails' gem and when i try to used it i get this error

```
TypeError: Object function (t,e){return new ce.fn.init(t,e,K)} has no method 'backstretch'

message: "Object function (t,e){return new ce.fn.init(t,e,K)} has no method 'backstretch'
stack: (...)
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error`
```

I got the error either way, using

```
jQuery.backstretch("path_to_photo")
```

or

```
$.backstretch("path_to_photo")
```

I'm using jQuery JavaScript Library v1.10.0 and Backstretch - v2.0.4

Comment: are you including backstretch in your asset pipeline? `//= require 'jquery.backstretch'`

Comment: yes, //= require 'jquery.backstretch' it's included, and also i can see the javascript in the network tab of the chrome inspector.

Comment: I found a work around, i just put jquery backstretch script in a partial.